# Maximum Length of Value in R Data Frame, RODBC

Tags: r, db2, rodbc

I am trying to do a simple query of a DB2 database using the RODBC package in R (myQuery<-sqlQuery(channel,paste0("..."))) One of the columns is a Varchar of length 3000. The resulting data frame shows a "NA" in that column when there should be text. Exporting it to csv also only shows "NA". A query in Access shows an odd character encoding (only after clicking on the cell). Is there a maximum length of a value in a R data frame or a maximum length of a field that can be pulled using RODBC? Or is it the encoding of the field that causes the "NA" to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did an end to end test on DB2 (LUW 9.7) and R (3.2.2 Windows) and it worked fine for me.**

SQL code:

```
create table test (foo varchar(3000));

--actual insert is 3000 chars
insert into test values ('aaaaaa .... a'); 

--this select worked fine in my normal SQL client
select * from test
```

R code:

```
long = sqlQuery(connection, "select * from test");

#Displays the 3000 character value.
long;
```

My guess is the problem is for some other reason than simply the size of the field:

- **Character encoding issues**.  If you are seeing something funny in Access, perhaps the content of the field is something not acceptable in the character encoding R is using, so it is being discarded.  (I'm not familiar with character encoding in R in particular, but it is in general a thorny issue for software development).
- **Overall size of the results**.  Maybe the problem is due to the overall length of a row rather than the length of a single field.  Is the query also returning lots of other stuff?  Have you tried a simple test of just this field?
- **Problem in another version.** Maybe you are using a different version than I was, and there is indeed a problem with your version.  If you think so, update your question with more information.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I am using 3.2.1 on Windows, so I don't think that's the problem. Just returning the field also results in NA. I think you're right in that it is the character encoding. I'll find another way to get to the data.